# How to encode field entities in URL in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, url

I made a form submit application via Spring MVC. After submitting the form, all values of input fields are visible in url.

**let's suppose that after submitting the generated URL is this:**

*SpringTuto/successA?name=FirstUser&designation=Student&country=XYZ&dob=2018%2F01%2F16&skills=paragliding&address.street_name=avenue+Road&address.city=New+City&address.district=New+District&address.pin_code=322343*

From the above url, I want to encode name, designation, country and all other parameters in some encrypted code.

After reading a few articles, i came to an understanding that I will use the URIeditor(org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.URIEditor) to encode. But I don't know how to use it. If anyone has another way to do this please share it.
Thanks in advance.

Here is my Controller Class.

@Controller
public class SpgController {

```
@ModelAttribute("header")
public Model addHeader(Model view) {
    int a = 10;
    return view.addAttribute(a);

}
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, "dob", new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, "name" , new NamepropertyEditor());
}



@RequestMapping("/main")
public ModelAndView go() {
    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("main");
    return view;
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/successA", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView method(@Valid @ModelAttribute("bean") Bean bean, BindingResult result ) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("main");
        return view;
    }

    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("successAnother");
    return view;

}
```

}

Here is the successAnother.jsp page

```
     <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form >
        Name: ${bean.name}<br/>
        Designation: ${bean.designation}<br/>
        DoB: ${bean.dob}<br/>
        Skills: ${bean.skills}<br/>
        Street: ${bean.address.street_name}<br/>
        City: ${bean.address.city}<br/>
        District: ${bean.address.district}<br/>
        PinCode: ${bean.address.pin_code}<br/>
        Country: ${bean.country}<br/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is main.jsp(Application form)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>  
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix = "spring" %>  

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Spring</title>
</head>
<body>

    <a href = "/SpringTuto/main?language=en">English</a>|<a href = "/SpringTuto/main?language=fr">French</a>|<a href = "/SpringTuto/main?language=hi">Hindi</a>

    <h3>${msg}</h3>
    <form:errors path = "bean.*"/>
    <form action="successA" method="get">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><spring:message code = "label.userName"/><input type="text" name="name">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><spring:message code = "label.userDesignation"/><input type="text" name="designation">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><spring:message code = "label.userCountry"/><input type="text" name="country">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <spring:message code = "label.userDoB"/><input type= "text" name = "dob"  >
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <spring:message code = "label.Skils"/><select name = "skills" multiple >
                        <option value= "driving">Driving</option>
                        <option value = "diving">Diving</option>
                        <option value = "swimming">Swimming</option>
                        <option value  = "paragliding">Paragliding</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h5><spring:message code = "label.userAddress"/></h5>
                        <spring:message code = "label.userStreetname"/><input type = "text" name = "address.street_name">
                        <spring:message code = "label.userCity"/> <input type = "text" name = "address.city">
                        <spring:message code = "label.userDistrict"/><input type = "text" name  = "address.district">
                        <spring:message code = "label.userPin"/><input type  = "text" name = "address.pin_code">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value=<spring:message code = "label.userSubmit"/>></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application supports `HTTPS`, then it can be achieved easily using spring security by doing some configuration as follows.

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https"/>
...
</http>
```

Integrating spring security with spring mvc is very simple.

Comment: Is there not any way to do this by Spring libraries or JRE, because I want to avoid coding in XML file.

Comment: you can actually do it in java(Java config) way as well. Pretty easy to do it. No XML required. I think, it is much more easy and the cleanest way. And once configured, no further action is required from your side